# SQL SELECT query without using aggregate function

Tags: sqlite

Write a query to find the names of symptoms that have been observed in at least two patients from Edmonton but no patient from Calgary.

I beleive nested query would be the solution, however I dont know how to proceed with this.

Table format:Patient (patient_ id, city) and stymptoms (patient_id, sym_name)

```
SELECT symptoms.sym_name
FROM patients, symptoms
WHERE  ???
```

Comment: How about `SELECT symptoms.sym_name FROM patients, symptoms WHERE patients.patient_id = symptoms.patient_id AND patients.city = 'edmonton' ` ?. Try using [DB Browser for SQLite](http://sqlitebrowser.org/) to execute the query.

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/11654)